# scala aggregate based on case class attribute

Tags: scala

aggregate by case class element and output in another output case class.
I tried getting the values as Map or List using `recs.groupBy(_.grade).mapValues(_.map(_.student))` . But i need to get it case class.Please advice.

```
object myApp extends App {


  val input: List[student] = List(student(1, 100), student(1, 101), student(2, 102))

  val output: List[studentsByGrade] = List(studentsByGrade(1, List(100, 101)), studentsByGrade(2, List(102)))

}


case class student(grade: Long,
                   student: Long)


case class studentsByGrade
(grade: Long,
 studentList: List[Long]
)
```

Comment: Instead of a `mapValues` use `.toList.map { case (grade, studentss) => ??? } ` it should be pretty straight forward to finish the code.

Comment: Not sure how to pass the aggregated student list in the above

Comment: You just need to construct an instance with `grade` and `studentss` following Luis' code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces the specified result.

```
input.groupMap(_.grade)(_.student).map(studentsByGrade.tupled)
```

---

Scala 2.12.x

```
input.groupBy(_.grade)
     .map{case (grd,ss) => studentsByGrade(grd, ss.map(_.student))}
     .toList  //optional
```

Comment: this feature available scala 2.13

Comment: Jasper, How can i use grouped (20)  here. I want to  add new lists if list of students exceeds 20  .( scala 2.12)

Comment: It's not clear whether you want to group the `output` list, or each of the `studentList` elements, or something else. I recommend you post a new question with a clear example of what you've got and what you want. (?Jasper?)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67962851/aggregating-case-class-by-attribute-and-limit-the-group-list-by-certain-number I have published this question in a different post.