# Aggregating case class by attribute and limit the group list by certain number

Tags: scala

I have a list of student grade &  student no. and aggregated based on student grade.

scala version 2.11
So the output of the below code will be :

```
studentsByGrade( 2, List(102) )
```

How ever i want to restrict the list of student by 2.So it will be spilled over to multiple lists.

```
studentsByGrade( 1, List(102,103) ) ,
studentsByGrade( 1, List(104) ) ,
studentsByGrade( 2, List(102) ))
```

```
object myApp extends App {


  val input: List[student] = List(student(1, 100), student(1, 101), student(2, 102) ,student(1,102),student(1,103),student(1,104) ) 

  val output: List[studentsByGrade] = List(studentsByGrade(1, List(100, 101)), studentsByGrade(2, List(102)))

}


case class student(grade: Long,
                   student: Long)


case class studentsByGrade
(grade: Long,
 studentList: List[Long]
)


//grouping by grade

input.groupBy(_.grade)
     .map{case (grd,ss) => studentsByGrade(grd, ss.map(_.student))}
     .toList
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `groupBy` method on **List** + a `flatMap` to achieve your desired result.
As I always say, the [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html) is your friend.

```scala
// I made some small changes on naming following the style-guide.
def groupByGradeWithLimit(students: List[Student], groupLimit: Int = 2): List[StudentsByGrade] =
  students
    .groupBy(_.grade)
    .iterator
    .flatMap {
      case (grade, students) =>
        students.grouped(groupLimit).map { studentList =>
          StudentsByGrade(grade, studentList.map(_.studentId))
        }
    }.toList
```

---

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/aXiUn6G9SOStZ4Lx4sRiig/6)*

Comment: Luis, Thnx a lot . groupMap not available in 2.11

Comment: @byomjan edited the answer to work on `2.11`